# Keeping session alive on background

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, parse-platform

I'm trying to write a login based app with parse.com

When my app was sent to background it logged out. I want to keep session alive when app was sent to background.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your App Delegate, check if there is a valid Parse User session and perform a segue to the right view controller or even replace the current root view controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        // Go to your logged in view controller
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"autoLoginSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre. I'll also use NSUserDefaults to save login credentials.

Comment: You're welcome.
I think you don't need to save the login credentials since Parse SDK already caches that on the currentUser object.

Comment: I quess i'll need if the app closed by the user. I need to call username and password from NSUserDefaults and log the user back. Unless the user logged out by itself. I searched but couldn't find, I'd like to know if there is any solution for that.